# disintegrate 3rd party tool from sandbox

Tags: integration

I have just integrated my sandbox with 3rd party marketing information tool now I want to disintegrate that tool to a sandbox so that I can integrate it with salesforce production org.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can go into Setup > Session Management, and remove the integration session. The third party tool will then be forced to login again. Refer to your third party tool for instructions on changing the login URL.